# alias to run dot slash (./) on a file without cd using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, executable

I have a directory like this:

```
/home/user/Project/
```

Inside `Project` and after many sub directories, I have a script names `ninja` that needs to be run with `./ninja`. In other words:

```
/home/user/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3/ninja
```

Of course, I can just `cd` into `Project` and execute `./ninja`. However, I am writing an alias to run that command via bashrc.

`alias runNinja = cd ~/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3 && ./ninja`

Can we do it 1 command?

`alias runNinja = .~/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3/ninja`

The above obviously doesnt work, or even this

`alias runNinja = ./home/user/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3/ninja`

TL,DR: How to shorten alias to run script in directories?

Comment: if the script needs to be run in the right working directory this will be hard to achieve with an alias. You should consider a shell function or a wrapper script instead.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376

Comment: You say shorten. Do you have a working but longer version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just *append* the path in the $PATH Variable in .bashrc like below:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3
```

And execute it from wherever you want in even without ./

```
$ ninja
```

But ofcourse  you can set alias also

```
alias runNinja='/home/user/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3/ninja'
```

And execute from wherever:

```
$ runNinja
```

If you deliberately wanted to be in that directory when running this ( Ex:if you are processing any file as input/output from that directory or dependency) , you have to write a function like below in your ~/.bashrc file or profile:

```
runNinja() { cd /home/user/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3 && ./ninja "$@" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aliases in `bash` are written

```
alias ninja="$HOME/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3/ninja"
```

(no spaces around the `=`).

I've also used the variable `$HOME` here, which will be expanded to the path of your home directory when the alias is defined.

Using a shell function instead:

```
ninja () {
    "$HOME/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3/ninja" "$@"
}
```

The `"$@"` will be expanded to any arguments that you may give on the command line.

If you *need* to change the current directory to `$HOME/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3` before running `./ninja`, you could do that in a function as well:

```
ninja () (
    cd "$HOME/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3" &&
    ./ninja "$@"
)
```

Note that I put the function body in a subshell (`(...)`).  This means that the `cd` will not change the current directory of the *current* shell, but only in the environment in the function.

You could obviously have written that as

```
ninja () {
    ( cd "$HOME/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3" && ./ninja "$@" )
}
```

The `&&` between `cd` and the `ninja` command ensures that `./ninja` will *not* be executed if the `cd` fails.

Shell functions may be declared wherever you would usually add aliases (possibly in `~/.bashrc`).

Answer (score 1):

You are so close. However the `.` is not a command, it is part of the file name.

The file `.` is in every directory, is is a directory it is the same directory as the one that it is in. `cd ././././././` will get you nowhere. `$PWD`, `.`, `./.`, and `././.` are all the same directory.

Therefore to run `/home/user/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3/ninja` you type `/home/user/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3/ninja`
To make an alias you do
`alias ninja="/home/user/Project/sub1/sub2/sub3/ninja"`